# IsAuthenticated users, no access to Login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my web application I have:
- login page .
- CreateNewUser page

I don't want to allow users access the Login and CreateNewUser pages after they have logged in with username and password.

- Should I write something like that in Login and CreateNewUsers Controller,  ?-

OR there is better ways ?

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    return RedirectToAction("NoAccessPage", "Account");
}
```

Comment: You could write an action filter to do this, but since it's likely to only be on a couple controller actions, your code above is probably fine.

Comment: Why not just leave it alone? If they are already logged in then showing them "NoAccessPage" is just a little odd. What you should be doing is forwarding them to a default homepage instead